# Relative, absolute and bloody quantum paths in PHP!

Tags: php, relative-path, absolute-path

I am building a web app (a forum), and it is to be integrated into various websites. The idea is that the folder location storing all the files is variable so that a webmin can put the forum wherever they like. I have, as usual, some PHP included files.

Say I have `global.php` and `envars.php` and want them included in `app_root.php`. The first two are stored in `./global/`, relative to `app_root.php`. Now, when I use `./` I get a file not found error. If I use just `global/` (no prepended slash), I get the same error.

I really need help on this :-(

The paths need to be relative to `app_root.php` and can't be absolute - the abs. path varies per installation.

Thanks for reading,

James

Comment: ./ means current folder, so that doesnt really help.  can you give some more idea of your directory structure? lacking any more info, all i could advise is to make everything absolute, and maybe store the paths as constants if you like instead of hard-coding

Comment: @jon_darkstar - I've decided to take that route on Mike B's recommendations - thank you.

Comment: no problem.  one thing -  depending on your webroot's setup and framework (or lack thereof) you might be able to store constants in something like .htaccess, System.xml, Config.xml, etc.  it could be slightly more appropriate to store path constants here than in regular source

Comment: That's a very good point, although for portability and ease of installation, as well as to remove .htaccess conflicts, in this case I think it better to use the `dirname(__FILE__)` solution. Thanks for the tips nonetheless!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is normally solved by creating a constant with an absolute path to the application.

Something like this in your app_root.php file

```
define('ROOT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__));
```

Then, to include other files just use something like

```
include ROOT_PATH . '/dir/file.php';
```

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to make it relative so there was one less field in the installer. Still, it's not hard to type a file path ;-P

Comment: @Jam it's not "path to the application", it's path to the actual file. The same relative path, different view. You can use `include 'dir/file.php';` as well. No difference. It's not actually a solution

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - Well, it works great for my uses, so I'm happy for now. If I find it stops working, I'll be the first to let you know...

Comment: @Jam no need to bother. I know it already. The best thing you can do is start to think instead of copypaste a code you do not even understand.